# Vlookup with duplicate values through AWK

Tags: awk

Need to vlookup from two different files having duplicate entries:

File 1

```
abc     10
xyz     20
bhy     30
hgf     40
```

File 2

```
a   abc     
b   xyz     
c   bhy     
d   abc     
e   abc     
f   xyz
```

Output required:

```
abc     10  a,d,e
xyz     20  b,f
bhy     30  c
hgf     40  Not_Available
```

Comment: What is `vlookup`? Do you actually use the first file for anything? It seems as if the output could be compiled from only the second file.

Comment: We can ignore 3rd column of File 2. Updated files are:

Comment: File 1:
abc     10
xyz     20
bhy     30

File 2:
a   abc     
b   xyz     
c   bhy     
d   abc     
e   abc     
f   xyz     

Output:
abc     10  a,d,e
xyz     20  b,f
bhy     30  c

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add any clarifications. Comments don't really count.

Comment: Have you made any efforts to solve this yourself? If yes, please show your work.

Comment: awk -F'[[:space:]]+|,' 'NR == FNR{ a[$2] = $1; next }  {  c = 0; r = $1" "$2"  OFS; for (i = 2; i <=  (c++? "," : "") a[$i] } if (!c) r = r $2;  print r  }' File 2 File1. Tried this but not getting desired output

Comment: FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$1
  next
}
{ if ($1 in a) {print $1, a[$1]} else {print $1, "NA"}  }
Tired this as well, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2 OFS; next }
     $2 in a { a[$2] = a[$2] (a[$2] ~ /\t$/? "" : ",") $1 }
     END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] }' OFS='\t' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
bhy 30  c
abc 10  a,d,e
xyz 20  b,f
```

---

For your last condition use the following modification:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2 OFS; next }
     $2 in a { a[$2] = a[$2] (a[$2] ~ /\t$/? "" : ",") $1 }
     END {
         for (i in a) print i, a[i] (a[i] ~ /\t$/? "Not_Available" : "")
     }' OFS='\t' file1 file2
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it is working.

Comment: @user279255, did it solve your issue?

Comment: Hi, Can you please guide how to add a comment in case there is some value which is not available in one of the file. e.g out put file should be:                                                                                       bhy 30  c
abc 10  a,d,e
xyz 20  b,f                                                                                          hgf 40 Not_Available

Comment: @user279255, make an update so I could see the extended output in formatted view

Comment: Hi, Updated the details.

Comment: @user279255, ok, see my update

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR == FNR {val[$1]=$2; next} 
    {items[$2] = items[$2] " " $1}
    END {
        for (a in val) {
            sub(/^ /, "", items[a])
            gsub(/ /, ",", items[a]) 
            print a, val[a], items[a]
        }
    }
' file1 file2
```

```
bhy     30      c
abc     10      a,d,e
xyz     20      b,f
```

If you want it sorted, pipe into `| sort -k2,2n`

Just for fun, a tricky bit of perl

```
perl -lae '
    if ($. == ++$nr) { $val{$F[0]} = $F[1] }
    else             { push @{$items{$F[1]}}, $F[0] }
  } continue {
    close ARGV if eof
  } END { 
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $_, $val{$_}, join(",", @{$items{$_}}) for keys %items 
' file1 file2
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it is working.

Comment: Which specific parts do you need help understanding? NR==FNR? arrays?

Comment: Array part of the command

Comment: Looking at this line `NR == FNR {val[$1]=$2; next}` what we have is: for each record of the first file (NR==FNR), set the "val" of the first field to be the second field. This maps "abc" to "10". This is known as an "associative array" where the array indices are arbitrary strings or numbers. Other languages call the associative array a "map" or a "hash" or a "dictionary".

Comment: We can test if a string is an index into the array with the test `"some string" in a`, (where "a" is the variable name of an associative array) and we can iterate over the indices of the array with `for (index in a) {do something with the "index" variable}`.

Comment: To extract the value stored for a particular index, we have the syntax `array[index]`, so here, `index = "abc"; print val[index]` prints `10`,